# Is it possible to use a custom Webpack Configuration when building an Angular Library?

Tags: angular, variables, webpack, sass, environment-variables

I have an Angular 8 library (*not application*) what is shared by other Angular Applications that I want to pass some ENV variables to. It seems the best way to do this might be via webpack, but I don't see any way to customize the library that is being built.

```
{
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    prependData: '$env: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ';',
  }
}
```

I know I can customize a Angular applications' Webpack configuration pretty easily.

Any advice?

Also I'm sure someone will ask (Why do you want to do this?) okay fair enough question. Because I want to set an Environmental variable that will be used in my SCSS files when they are build for the library.

Answer (score 2):

Angular libraries do not use Webpack they use a different kind of build system called `build-ng-packagr`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) , then use `customWebpackConfig` in your `angular.json` like that

```
"architect": {
  ...
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser"
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js",
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I think I figured out why this is not possible. Angular libraries do not use webpack they use something else. `ng-packagr`

Comment: Is there any solution to this that supprts ng-packagr?